# class without init method accepting arguments

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    
    from sqlalchemy import Sequence
    Base = declarative_base()
    Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
    class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'users'
        id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(50))
        fullname = Column(String(50))
        nickname = Column(String(50))
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                                    self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)
    
    class User1(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'users1'
        id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(50))
        fullname = Column(String(50))
        nickname = Column(String(50))
        
        def __init__(self, name, fullname, nickname):
            self.name = name
            self.fullname = fullname
            self.nickname = nickname

    
        def __repr__(self):
            return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                                    self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)
    
 ed_user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', nickname='edsnickname')
 ed_user = User1(name='edd', fullname='Edd Jones', nickname='edsnick')
```

i picked up this piece of code from the sqlalchemy documentation website, I think everything is okay, but i have a problem understanding the last line, the class user inherits from the base class, buy the user class is not having an init methods in other to accept any argument. can some please explain this to me.. thanks. this two-class achieves the same result they create a table, but in the second instance, the User1 has an **init** method declared, so obviously the creation of the table happens in the base class, but in the second instance the class and instance variable were declared I want to know how will the base class be able to create the table if it is not receiving any data from the child class.

Comment: did you check if `Base` got a `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):` ?

Comment: No @PatrickArtner let me take a look

Comment: "the class `User` inherits from the `Base` class" - then it inherits also the `__init__` method

Comment: If you do not define a method, you inherit the parents method with the same name. In this case `User` doesn't have a `__init__` method. Does `Base` have an `__init__` method? In that case that will be used. If it doesn't, which is the parent of `Base`? If it doesn't have anyone written explictly, the parent is `object` and its `__init__` method will be used.

Comment: There is *always* an `__init__` method. The question is whether your class *overrides* the inherited method, or simply uses it. *Something* is processing all those class attributes in a way that makes the attributes used inside `__repr__` available. (Could be an inherited `__init__`, or inherited `__new__`, or the metaclass.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your question well, you want to understand why the User class contains no `__init__` method yet it was able to receive arguments, just as @snakecharmerb answered, the User class was able to receive arguments even though it has no **init** method of it own, this is possible because the class from which User inherited called base have all ready implemented the **init** method, so you can use the **init** method from the base class without declaring anyone explicitly. for instance if you inherit a car from your dad, you will be able to use that car even though you don't have a car you bought for yourself.

in the second class User1 the constructor or the **init** method is used to create a new instance or new row inside the table, every instance of the User1 class you create will be equivalent to a new row in the table

```
class User(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, index=True)
    hash_passwrd = db.Column(db.String(200))



    def __init__(self, email, username, password):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.hash_passwrd = generate_password_hash(password)


adams = user('adams@email.com', 'adams', 'adams@1')
ben= user('ben@email.com', 'ben', 'ben@1')
poolo= user('poolo@email.com', 'poolo', 'poolo@1')
```

somewhere in your in your code you will have your database object

```
db.session.add_all([adams, ben, poolo])
db.session.commit()
```

now these three class object are now rows inside your table.

when you instaciate a class like this in flask it means you are creating a new row inside your user table, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Python is a very dynamic language. There are several ways to achieve this. One is inheriting from its superclass, as @vrevolverr says. But unfortunately here is not this case. You can confirm that by running `print(Base.__init__ is User.__init__)`, which will give you a `False`. That means `User.__init__` is not inherited from `Base`.

Another evidence is that `print('__init__' in User.__dict__)` gives you `True`, which means that `User` class has its own `__init__` method. And this method can only be given by its metaclass. So the answer comes out. By the way, in your case, this metaclass is `DeclarativeMeta` in `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative`.

Just FYI. Simply put, metaclass can do something during the creating process of a class. For example, add a method to this class. This is where your `__init__` comes from.

---

Update:

My original answer also solves your second question. But I still want to add some comments.

First, does `User1.__init__` take effect? The answer is NO. Try this simple test:

```py
def init(self, name, fullname, nickname):
    self.name = name
    self.fullname = fullname
    self.nickname = nickname

class User(Base):
    ...
    __init__ = init

print(User.__init__ is init) # False
```

You can see that the `__init__` method defined by you is already replaced.

Then, how to perform this "magic"? See below:

```py
def init1(self):
    pass

def init2(self):
    pass

class MyMeta(type):
    # You can also do this in __new__
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.__init__ = init2
        type.__init__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    __init__ = init1

print(MyClass.__init__ is init1) # False
print(MyClass.__init__ is init2) # True
```

Answer (score 3):

If the child class (the class which inherits) does not have a class constructor (**init** method), the child class will call the constructor of the parent class. However, if the child class has a constructor, it will call its own constructor.

Consider the following examples:

**Child class without constructor**

```
class ParentClass:

    def __init__(self, parent_arg):
        self.parent_arg = parent_arg


class ChildClass(ParentClass):

    def child_method(self):
        print(self.parent_arg)


c = ChildClass(parent_arg="Test")
c.child_method() # Output: Test
```

**Child class with constructor**

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass):

    def __init__(self, child_arg):
        self.child_arg = child_arg

    def child_method(self):
        print(self.child_arg) # Output: Child Test

        # This will throw an error since this attribute is created by the parent constructor
        print(self.parent_arg)

c = ChildClass(child_arg="Child Test")
c.child_method()
```

**To call the parent constructor, pass the arguments for parent class through the constructor of child class and use super() to call the constructor of parent class**

```
def __init__(self, child_arg, parent_arg):
    self.child_arg = child_arg
    super().__init__(parent_arg)

print(self.parent_arg) # This will then work
```

Comment: hi, thanks i edited the question again can you help me out??

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the below little snippet helps to explain what is going on:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(A):

    def printme(self):
        print(self.a)

b = B(10)
b.printme()
```

result

```
10
```

class `B` inherits class `A` which has an `__init__` method that defines `self.a`, which is called when the instance `B` is created  which is then used in class `B` method `printme`.

Comment: hi, thanks i edited the question again can you help me out??

Answer (score 1):

> so obviously the creation of the table happens in the base class

This is a misconception.  The model class defines the structure of a table, and that table is created when `Base.metadata.create_all` or similar is called.  This is independent of the creation of any instances of the class.

Creating an instance of the model class - `user = User(...)` is the equivalent of creating a row on the table, not the table itself.  If an `__init__` method assigns values to the class' attributes, these values become the row values.  If no `__init__` function is defined, the declarative machinery calls a default constructor (or a function passed as `declarative_base`'s [constructor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.constructor) argument) to assign the values passed to the Model's constructor.